How to add static functions that use Tasks in Swift Task extensions
I'm curious if anyone has run into this question before. I initially ran into problems when trying to use an extension to Task that calls Task.sleep from a non-async function  static function, then further digging has led me to this simpler discussion point.
This is valid Swift:
struct Foo {}

extension Foo {
    static func bar() async throws {
    }
    
    static func bar() {
        Task {
            try await bar()
        }
    }
}

But the following is not:
extension Task {
    static func bar() async throws {
    }
    
    static func bar() {
        Task {
            try await bar()
        }
    }
}

This gives me two errors (in Xcode 15.4):

Referencing initializer 'init(priority:operation:)' on 'Task' requires the types 'Failure' and 'any Error' be equivalent

'Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Success'.


Why is the compiler treating the Task extension differently, and how do we solve this? I know that Success and Failure are two placeholder types for the Task generic, but I don't think they should be affecting the Task instance in the bar static function's implementation.

When you write the name of the extended type in an extension, without any type parameters, it is assumed that you mean to use already-declared type parameters. After all, this is what happens in the type's own declaration:
struct Foo<T> {
    func foo() {
        let x = Foo() // "Foo()" means "Foo<T>()"
    }
    
    var bar: Foo { // this means "var bar: Foo<T>"
        Foo()
    }
}

In an extension, it is "as if" you are in the type's declaration
extension Set {
    func foo() {
        let x = Set() // "Set()" means "Set<Element>()"
    }
    
    var bar: Set { // this means "var bar: Set<Element>"
        []
    }
}

So in your case, it assumes that you mean Task<Success, Failure> { ... }, i.e. you are creating a task that returns whatever type the caller wants, and can throw whatever type of error the caller wants to throw. This is obviously not what you want.
You should add constraints to Success and Failure:
extension Task where Success == Void, Failure == any Error {
    static func bar() async throws {
    }
    
    static func bar() {
        Task {
            try await bar()

            // as discussed below, Task.sleep requires that Success == Never, Failure == Never
            // but writing 'Task' on its own here would mean Task<Void, any Error>
            try await Task<Never, Never>.sleep(...)
        }
    }
}


It is also possible to directly write the type parameters out, without adding the constraints to Success and Failure
Task<Void, any Error> {
    try await bar()
    try await Task<Never, Never>.sleep(...)
}

However, this makes the call site more cumbersome - you cannot just write:
Task.bar()

because Task needs two type parameters and the compiler cannot infer them.
Notice how other static methods on Task also constrains the Success and Failure types. e.g. the documentation for sleep says:

Available when Success is Never and Failure is Never.

This is to help the compiler infer the type parameters so that the caller can just write Task.sleep(...) instead of Task<Never, Never>.sleep(...). The exact type that Success and Failure are constrained to isn't very important.

Thank you for that response. I think it answers very well the question of why an extension to Task is different from an extension to Foo. But if I try making a Task extension as you've specified, and define my non-async bar to call try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1000), then I get errors. Changing the constraints on the extension to where Success == Never, Failure == Never gives different errors but still doesn't work. So again, it seems that the constraints on the extension are affecting what the Task in the implementation is doing, and that doesn't seem right.

@CuriousJorge if you want to call Task.sleep here, you should write Task<Never, Never>.sleep(...). I believe the reason for this is explained adequately in my answer.

@CuriousJorge Similarly, if you want to use where Success == Never, Failure == Never, then you should write Task<Void, Never> { ... }.

@CuriousJorge "it seems that the constraints on the extension are affecting what the Task in the implementation is doing" Correct. Task (on its own, without any type parameters) in a Task extension always means Task<Success, Failure>, so changing the constraints on Success and Failure changes the meaning of Task. Why doesn't that seem right?

I confirm that Task<Never, Never> works the constraints you gave. The 2nd one doesn't work for me, but let's ignore that for now and concentrate on the last question. None of this makes sense to me, because it seems to me that when I instantiate a new child Task, it shouldn't care about the Success/Return types of the parent task. I'm not even sure that's the situation I'm dealing with. I mean, what's the mechanism is for linking the signature of a static function on the Task type to the context it's called in? That's probably the missing piece of information preventing understanding for me.

@CuriousJorge Oops I meant Task<Void, any Error> { ... } in that comment. Child/parent tasks are irrelevant here. Task { ... } creates a top-level task. The "mechanism" you are talking about is two-fold. First, sleep is declared in a Task extension with the constraints where Success == Never, Failure == Never. We know that because the documentation says "available when...". When we write Task.sleep(...) outside of a Task extension, the compiler can infer from these constraints that we actually mean Task<Never, Never>.sleep(...).

@CuriousJorge Secondly, in this particular case you are calling Task.sleep in a Task extension. As explained by the first half of the answer, instead of inferring that you mean Task<Never, Never>.sleep(...) from the constraints of the extension in which sleep is declared, the compiler assumes you mean Task<Success, Failure>.sleep(...). So if Success and Failure are not constrained in your extension, you cannot call Task.sleep(...).

@CuriousJorge If sleep had been declared without those constraints, then e.g. Task<String, Error>.sleep(...) would have also been valid. This makes it quite annoying to call, because you have to specify two unnecessary type parameters (what sleep does doesn't depend on either Success or Failure). You would not have been able to just say Task.sleep(...) because Task has two type parameters and the compiler cannot infer them. But by adding these constraints, it becomes necessary to specify the two type parameters when you call it in a Task extension, as explained above.

"... the compiler can infer ..." Well, that's a surprise. It seems arbitrary, but useful. I have no knowledge that says this must be so (other than the usefulness). This raises so many questions in my head! Let me play around with all the information you've given me. Thank you for it all!

After sitting on this a bit and carefully going over everything above, it is all clear now. Thanks again, Sweeper!

For anyone who makes it this far into the comments, let me summarise the discussion. In the extension to Foo, the compiler is able to infer that the Task being used in the non-async bar should have Success == Void and Failure == any Error, based on the signature of the call to  the async bar in that Task.

But in the extension to Task, the inference of the placeholder types takes lower precedence to the assumption that any Tasks used in the function should be of the same type that the extension is for. The Xcodes error messages don't give us much clarity that that's what's going on, but nothing new there.

So the solution, is to override the compiler assumption by explicitly specifying the placeholder types (the same ones that the compiler would have inferred in a non-Task extension context) for the Task being created in the non-async bar.

I would also add that I think that since my bar function doesn't use the type for which it is being defined, my extension should be constrained to Success == Never, Failure == Never, just like the extension in which sleep is defined.
